# Can We use xampp as Online server in Google cloud ubuntu vm instance

Tags: php, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, xampp, google-compute-engine

Hi to all and Thanks in advance,

I am new to google cloud platform. Recently i created one google account and created one Ubuntu vm instance on that.Meanwhile, downloaded free version of xampp(php mysql server) from apache and installed on it.And also pointing one domain to that IP.I have a plan to host more website on(by making virtual host) it.I don't know whether its wright or wrong. I am really grateful if you are answering my below queries.

1.Whether its secure or not. If no, how to configure secure xampp server.Please also mention
alternative options.
If yes, to do something to get it right?.
2.Please tell me, the proper way to make ubuntu apache server on google cloud platform

I am very much eager to hear from you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already [created a VM instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#publicimage) and installed based on Ubuntu and installed [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) on it. In general there's no difference in installing and configuring software on standard server or GCE VM.

Have a look at the tutorial [Setting Up LAMP on Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-lamp):

> This page shows you how to get a LAMP stack running on a Google
>   Compute Engine virtual machine instance. Follow the steps in this
>   tutorial to configure LAMP on a Debian, Ubuntu, or CentOS instance.

and  check if you missed something.

In addition, I'd recommend you a few extra steps:

- [reserve a static external IP address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address) and [assigning it to your VM instance instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#IP_assign).
- use appropriate to your load [machine type](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types) instead of mentioned in the tutorial `f1-micro` (you can change it later).
- learn more about [GCP Firewall](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) to use it instead of firewall on your VM instance.
- [create snapshots of your persistent disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/scheduled-snapshots) to protect your data.
- choose DNS servers for your domains: it could be [Google Cloud DNS](https://cloud.google.com/dns) or other DNS servers.
- think about [reservation of Compute Engine zonal resources](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reserving-zonal-resources), it could be helpful in some cases.
- check [Marketplace](https://cloud.google.com/marketplace) for preconfigured LAMP solutions.

**Going back to your questions**:

1. To avoid some obvious security issues you should follow [community tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#publicimage), official documentations, security recommendations for used software and common sense.
2. You're able to install LAMP manually (as you already did) or use preconfigured solution from [Marketplace](https://cloud.google.com/marketplace).

Comment: Thanks Serhii, I will go through your suggestions and do recommended changes on my system.

Comment: It am getting any issues later. I will get back to you. Once again thanks

Comment: Thank you! Please upvote/accept my answer if it was helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use centos to configure your apache mysql php to run your site. For more info visit the link here,

https://www.wlpbasic.tech/how-to-configure-a-lamp-on-centos-7/